# The Tree of Knowledge according to Enoch

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees, fruits

In the Biblical tradition the Forbidden Fruit of [the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_the_knowledge_of_good_and_evil) in Eden is commonly thought to be [apple, grape, pomegranate, fig, carob, etrog or citron, pear, or mushrooms.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_fruit)

According to [the pseudepigraphic Book of Enoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch),

> *"It was like a species of the Tamarind tree, bearing fruit which resembled grapes extremely fine; and its fragrance extended to a considerable distance. I exclaimed, How beautiful is this tree, and how delightful is its appearance!" (1 Enoch 31:4).*

What tree best suits **this** description? The [Carob](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceratonia_siliqua) tree (Ceratonia siliqua, known as St John's bread, locust bean, locust-tree, carob bush) seems an *OK* candidate **except that** it's male flowers (rather then it's fruit) resemble grapes exceedingly fine, not it's big chunky seedpods.

Any candidates?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an identification question that doesn't have a clear botanical description of the plant, or photographs showing enough detail for a positive id.

Comment: I think you should check online. I think there are few books about biblical plants, and I saw in a botanical garden a collection of "biblical plants" (I think in Copenhagen). As far I know, nobody here is expert on wild plant on that region (Turkey, Iraq, Iran, Armenia, and possibly more east).

Comment: I think they are asking if any of the trees in their description meet all of the "Enoch" Tree of Knowledge criteria - Bearing fruit "like" grapes, highly scented, and delightful appearance. I don't think any meet all three. Mushrooms aren't even plants. Pomegranate is more of a bush. Citron and Fig have other connotations in religious tradition. Apples and pears have scented flowers, but I would not call them delightful in appearance. Possibly Carob? Does Carob have scented flowers?

Comment: Very unlikely that the Tree would be an apple unless the Garden was in Asia, since apples are native to Kazakhstan.

Comment: i've heard somewhere it was the quince

Comment: I read that in fact the "trees" in Eden the sin with the apple the snake.  All this wasn't  as we think it is as they are a metaphor to a much greater event

Comment: Come to think of it, Carob tree leaves do resemble Tamarind tree leaves. I think it could be a Carob tree. They use Carob trees in the Middle East for landscaping. They are very attractive trees.

Comment: @user22542 I read they smell like human semen. Something to do with the chemical composition.